# For which spaces $S^n$ ($n\geq 2$) is a universal covering space?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-group, covering-spaces

I know that $S^n$ $(n\geq 2)$ is a universal covering space for itself and $\mathbb{RP}^n$. But my question is, for which spaces (up to homotopy equivalence) is $S^n$ ($n\geq 2$) a universal covering space?

Or at least, if $S^n$ is a universal covering space for $X$, can we have any information about fundamental group $\pi_1 (X)$ (or homotopy groups generally) and homology groups $H_i (X)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can have a look at the book of conner and floyd. They study free actions of finite groups on spheres. The fundamental group will be isomorphic to the group that acts. Higher homotopy groups are isomorphic. Homology groups are more tricky

Comment: This is essentially the question of which groups act freely on $S^n$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1575798/127263).

Comment: You definitely have lens spaces whose covers are odd dimensional spheres

Comment: To summarize the comments so far: The question consists of two parts:
1) Which groups act freely on spheres ?
2) Given one such group, what are the possible homotopy types of quotients ?
And lens spaces already show that there can be more than one homotopy type for such a group.

Comment: The case of cyclic groups and arbitrary actions on odd-dimensional spheres can be found in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.1196.pdf.

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you very much for your comment. Could you please tell me why my question is equivalent to the question of which groups act freely on $S^n$? Why if $S^n$ is a covering for $X$, then $X=S^n /G$ where $G=\pi_1 (X)$ acts freely on $S^n$ and conversely?

Comment: This is standard covering space theory. Since $S^n$ is simply connected, it must be a universal cover of $X$, so it has an action of $\pi_1(X)$ which quotients it back to $X$. See for instance Hatcher's book for the details.

Comment: @Wojowu I got it now. Thank you for the comment and the reference.

Answer (score 14):

The answer is quite complicated. To begin with, the universal cover of your space $X$ is a sphere $S^n$ with a free action of a finite group $G=\pi_1(X)$. The group $G$ has to have periodic cohomology. The transgression of the sphere class is a periodicity element $\zeta \in H^{n+1}(G,\mathbb{Z})$, and $H^*(X;k)\cong H^*(G,k)/(\bar\zeta)$ for any field $k$. A finite group has periodic cohomology if and only if every abelian $p$-subgroup is trivial or cyclic for every prime $p$; or equivalently, odd Sylow subgroups are cyclic and $2$-Sylow subgroups are either cyclic or (generalised) quaternion. However, not every finite group with these properties can act freely on a sphere. Jack Milnor showed that the symmetric group $\Sigma_3$ cannot. There is much more to say, and I recommend the book of Davis and Milgram, "A survey of the spherical space form problem" as well as Part III of J. A. Wolf's book "Spaces of constant curvature".

Comment: I also recommend the papers of Madsen, Thomas and Wall on the topological spherical space form problem.

Answer (score 12):

A nice and quick survey on the groups acting freely on the sphere is given in chapter 3 of [https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/ictp2006/lecturenotes/skowronski.pdf](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Ebernhard.keller/ictp2006/lecturenotes/skowronski.pdf) .
Theorem 3.26 gives a nice characterisation of such finite groups $G$ due to Madsen-Thomas-Wall: they are exactly the finite groups whose abelian subgroups are cyclic and have no dihedral subgroups.
Equivalently, they are the finite groups with at most one element of order 2 and this has to be central then.

Comment: Dear @Mare thank you very much for your answer. It means that if $X$ is a CW-complex of dimension $n$ with $\pi_1 (X)=G$ which is a finite group whose abelian subgroups are cyclic and have no dihedral subgroups, then $\tilde{X}=S^n$. Am I right?